# Multiply/Clone multiple times objects inside and array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, clone

Having an array of objects in this format:

```
const data = [
{country_id: 1, country: "Greece", value: 3},
{country_id: 2, country: "Cyprus", value: 2},
{country_id: 3, country: "Turkey", value: 4}
]
```

how can I multiply/clone each of the objects to get the following array of objects using JavaScript? I want to multiply each object as many times as specified in `value` and get a new array.

```
const new_data = [
{id: 1, country_id: 1, country: "Greece", value: 3},
{id: 2, country_id: 1, country: "Greece", value: 3},
{id: 3, country_id: 1, country: "Greece", value: 3},
{id: 4, country_id: 2, country: "Cyprus", value: 2},
{id: 5, country_id: 2, country: "Cyprus", value: 2},
{id: 6, country_id: 3, country: "Turkey", value: 4},
{id: 7, country_id: 3, country: "Turkey", value: 4},
{id: 8, country_id: 3, country: "Turkey", value: 4},
{id: 9, country_id: 3, country: "Turkey", value: 4}
]
```

My best attempt so far is this one using Object.assign but unfortunately the map returns the same array as in `data`:

```
const new_data = data.map((d, i) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < d.mult; ++i) {
      Object.assign({}, d[i]);
    }
    return d;
 })
```

Comment: Object.assign({}, d[i], {id: i}) ... I think this should assign a new id too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this, where you simply fill an array with `value` elements, and map it to a clone of the original element:

```js
const data = [
{country_id: 1, country: "Greece", value: 3},
{country_id: 2, country: "Cyprus", value: 2},
{country_id: 3, country: "Turkey", value: 4}
]

console.log(
    data.flatMap((el) => new Array(el.value).fill(null).map(e => ({...el}))))
```

Comment: I like this approach, but the answer could use some supporting text to explain how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `Array.from()` and `reduce`. Try this-

Here you can create a temporary array using `Array.from({length: X})`. Here the `{length: X}` object says the `from` method to create an array with the length of `X`.

After that, the callback function of the `Array.from()` method returns the current item for every iteration. That's it.

```js
const data = [
  {country_id: 1, country: "Greece", value: 3},
  {country_id: 2, country: "Cyprus", value: 2},
  {country_id: 3, country: "Turkey", value: 4}
];

const res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const tmp = Array.from({length: curr.value}, () => curr);
  acc.push(...tmp);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to just create a new array, loop through the old one and add duplicates (with the new `id` field) to the result array:

```js
const data = [
    { country_id: 1, country: "Greece", value: 3 },
    { country_id: 2, country: "Cyprus", value: 2 },
    { country_id: 3, country: "Turkey", value: 4 }
]

const result = [];

let id = 0;
for (const row of data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < row.value; i++) {
        const newRow = {
            ...row, // copy old data
            id: ++id, // but set this field and increase `id`
        };
        result.push(newRow);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

If you want to use something like `.map`, you'd need to use `.flatMap` or `.map` followed by `.flat()`. Your (flat)map would return an array with the `value` new rows. You'd still have to fix the `country_id` though.